# Assigning fixed value to top margin

Tags: margins, dvi

I am using TeXnicCenter .When I generate the .dvi file top margins look decent. Somehow on converting the .dvi to pdf the top margins get squashed. Is this normal? How can I ensure that an inch of margin from the top is always maintained on every page in the final output pdf?

Comment: What class are you using? Is there a reason why you don't use `pdf(la)tex` or `xe(la)tex`?

Answer (score 2):

It can be caused by changes during the conversion from DVI to PDF.

You could

- Use pdfLaTeX for directly producing PDF, since this is your final output format. pdfLaTeX further offers nice microtypographic features available by using the [`microtype`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package and more direct access to PDF features such as metadata.
- Use the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package for specifying the margins, it takes care of the driver (such as dvips) and ensures that the desired paper size and pargins will be used.
- If you really need conversion, check out and use the right options for calling the conversion command `dvips` or `dvipdfmx` etc.

My choice would be using `geometry` (or [`typearea`](http://ctan.org/pkg/typearea)) together with pdfLaTeX.